# Game Center Mutliplayer

Tags: iphone, game-center

If I'd want to implement multiplayer checkers game using game center API, does it mean that I don't have to write a server, and I'll be using game center's servers?

I'm new to game center, and I'd like to know its use.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great tutorial that will get you up and running in a couple of hours!

[Beginning Turn Based Gaming with iOS5](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5480/beginning-turn-based-gaming-with-ios-5-part-1)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Obsolutely you don't want to write any servers. The apple's `Game Center` handles it. First of all you need to import `GameKit` framework. It will maintain game center servers.In  `Game Center` you have `Leaderboards` (Where you can see the scores of all players who are using your app), and `Achievements` (You can setup some achievements that when a user crosses particular scores 1000, 2000, 3000.. etc. in your app). The `Leaderboards` and `achievements` are two different viewControllers you can show them through coding. For More Details You can visit the following link http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html it is very clear. And if you have any doubts feel free to contact me. I have implemented Leaderboards and achievements recently, but not multiplayer features. And to perform all these you have to enable `GameCenter` in your `iTunes` account.

Comment: Actually, It will take lot of time for me to read.. And I have some work now. But I can suggest this tutorial http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/Matchmaking/Matchmaking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH9-SW1 because i read it 1 month back but i didn't did Multiplayer feature. It will be very useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

As matter of fact in order to have a good multiplayer game experience, you need to consider eventually writing server side code that saves the user data in your database.

I have experienced the same scenario and ended it up using **[Parse](http://parse.com)** along with push notifications.

**If you insist you can do the following with Game Center :**

With Game Center services you can connect players to each others either by **Real-Time Matches** or **Turn-Based Matches**. Everything is fine as long as you don't care about the user data storage or the game experience!